# How to make straight mines?

Tags: medieval-engineers

Mining through a mountain, I see that, unlike Minecraft, it is very hard, on Medieval Engineers, to make a straight mine without some aid. But I don't know which aid I could use.

Masons/bricklayers use some lines to ensure the bricks are all aligned on a straight line. I believe this technology already existed on Medieval Ages.

How can I do this? Or is there a better way to ensure that I'm not making a circular cave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheap Planks will do the trick, as they can only be rotated 90º:

[image]